# How to dynamically query a for-loop using url paramaters with axios and vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, wordpress-rest-api

I recently started to experiment with the WordPress Rest API and VueJs. I am trying to accomplish the following:

- I use Axios to fetch an API URL (my WP REST API website) to build a list of posts. This works perfectly using the code(s) below.
- Next (this is what I can't manage to make it work), I need to be able to 'filter' the for loop using url parameter queries. The parameter is 'country'. Thus, when clicking on a button 'France', e.g. the parameter: ?country=france should be added to the base URL.
- Basically I tried to add simple functions on button clicks to these buttons (france & portugal). Please check my code to see what I tried so far.

HTML Code

```
<div class="row">

    <button v-on:click="getFrance" id="france" class="m-2">France</button>
    <button v-on:click="getPortugal" id="portugal" class="m-2">Portugal</button>

    <form class="form-inline" v-on:submit.prevent="searchCountry">
        <input type="text" id="nameInput" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" placeholder="Frankrijk" v-model="country">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
    </form>
    {{country}}
</div>

<div class="row">
    <template>
        <div class="col-6" v-for="post of posts" :key="post.id">

            <div class="card">

                <img v-bind:src="post.acf.header_picture.url" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image cap">

                <div class="card-body v-html">
                    <h5>{{ post.title.rendered }}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <a><button class="btn-sm btn-warning">Read more</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      country : '',
      posts : [] }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('<<WP REST API URL>>', {
        params: {
          country: this.country
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.posts = response.data
    })
  },
  methods : {
    getFrance: function(){
      this.country = 'france'
    },
    getPortugal: function(){
      this.country = 'portugal'
    }
  }
})
```

EDIT: I added the Response Data of the URL as requested. However, it's quite a big chunk of data, so let me know if this is not what you're looking for.

```
acf: Object
about_accommodation: "<ul>↵<li><strong>Tent</strong>: de tenten zijn voor 4 personen en bestaan uit 2 delen die beide geschikt zijn voor 2 personen. Naast het slaapdeel is er een plek waar de bagage kan liggen, wel zo fijn dus. Er is hier geen slaapmateriaal aanwezig, dus je dient zelf een matje, slaapzak en kussen mee te nemen. Het is mogelijk om zo&#8217;n &#8216;compartiment&#8217; privé te boeken.</li>↵<li><strong>Sheddie</strong>: deze gezellige houten huisjes zijn een stuk comfortabeler dan de tenten en zijn geschikt voor 2 personen. Er is een groot bed aanwezig, waar 2 personen in kunnen slapen. Je kunt ter plekke beddengoed huren of zelf een slaapzak en kussen meenemen. Ook is er voldoende ruimte voor je bagage en zelfs een surfplank. Je kunt er net staan, wel zo makkelijk om je even op jezelf om te kleden voor de surfsessie. Ook deze kun je privé boeken.</li>↵<li><strong>Sheddie Deluxe</strong>: deze tenten zijn nog groter dan de sheddies en dus nog een stuk comfortabeler. Je kunt kiezen tussen 2 losse bedden of een groot 2-persoonsbed, ideaal voor koppels. Ook hier zijn matrassen aanwezig en heb je de optie om een beddengoedpakket bij te boeken. Indien je deze optie privé wilt, is dat mogelijk.</li>↵<li><strong>Tipi-Deluxe: </strong>De Tipi Deluxe is een prachtig ruimte tipi-tent met twee losse of 1 groot bed met een mooie aankleding. Dit is verblijven in stijl!</li>↵</ul>↵"
about_activities: "<ul>↵<li><strong>Party:</strong> 18+, dat betekent party! Vanaf het surfkamp kun je lopend naar tal van leuke barretjes die tot in de vroege uurtjes open zijn</li>↵<li><strong>Trips: </strong>tijdens jouw verblijf kun je deelnemen aan de daguitstap naar San Sebastian, een fantastische stad die zeker een bezoekje waard zijn. Ontdek de echte gastronomie die Spanje te bieden heeft</li>↵<li><strong>Yoga:</strong> kies voor de yogalessen voor de ideale ontspanning en een leuke afwisseling met het surfen. Dit is de beste manier om je spieren even helemaal bij te laten komen na een flinke inspanning in het water</li>↵<li><strong>Skate &amp; Beach:</strong> ook naast het surfen is er van alles te doen. Cruise over de boulevard van Moliets en geniet van het vrije leven</li>↵</ul>↵"
about_facilities: Array(8)
about_guests: "<p>In het surfkamp vind je vooral Nederlandstaligen, de meesten tussen de 18 en de 25 jaar oud. De sheddies zijn perfect om als koppel of vrienden te verblijven maar ook solo reizigers weten een weg te vinden naar Surfblend Moliets</p>↵"
about_meals: "<ul>↵<li><strong>Eten:</strong> het halfpension is zeker aan te raden. Je zult 8 x ontbijten (incl. nadat je aankomt in het surfkamp na de busreis) en 5 x wordt er een divers en lekker diner geserveerd. Het hoogtepunt voor velen is de wekelijkse barbecue, gegarandeerd het begin van een mooie avond. In Zarautz zelf zijn er een aantal leuke opties voor lunch, maar voor ontbijt en diner is de maaltijd-optie aan te raden – wel zo makkelijk en het is ook nog eens heel erg lekker</li>↵<li><strong>Dieetwensen:</strong> het is geen probleem indien je een bepaalde dieetwens hebt. Geef dit van te voren even aan bij de kampleiding</li>↵<li><strong>Kookfaciliteiten:</strong> in het surfkamp zijn verder geen kookfaciliteiten aanwezig die door de gasten kunnen worden gebruikt</li>↵</ul>↵"
about_surf_conditions: "<ul>↵<li><strong>Beginners:</strong> beginnende surfers raden wij de cursus van 15 uur ten zeerste aan. Zeker in het begin is surfen een vrij lastig te leren sport, waarbij goede training vereist is.</li>↵<li><strong>Intermediate:</strong> intermediate surfers raden wij de cursus van 10 uur ten zeerste aan.</li>↵<li><strong>Gevorderd: </strong>gevorderde surfers kunnen ervoor kiezen om alleen gebruik te maken van het surfmateriaal.</li>↵</ul>↵"
about_surf_holiday: "<ul>↵<li><strong>Het kamp: </strong>dit surfkamp biedt werkelijk alles: surfen, veel fun, leuke activiteiten en uiteraard een flinke dosis party! Alle gasten zijn ten minste 18 jaar oud en hierdoor ontstaat er een leuke sfeer waar iedereen uit is op hetzelfde: een fantastische tijd hebben. Het prachtige surfstrand van Molietes bevindt zich op loopafstand van het surfkamp, ideaal dus. En ook de vele barretjes in het centrum kun je gemakkelijk bereiken. Ben jij klaar voor dé surfvakantie van 2020?</li>↵<li><strong>Moliets: </strong>dit Franse dorpje ademt surf, meer dan waar dan ook. In de zomer komen hier surfers van alle hoeken uit de wereld naartoe om de beroemde golven van Moliets te proberen. Ook is er een gezellige boulevard met enkele horecagelegenheden.</li>↵<li><strong>Vervoer: </strong>wat erg fijn is, is dat Moliets vanuit Nederland en België met de bus bereikbaar is. Zie onderaan deze pagina ‘vervoer’ voor meer informatie.</li>↵</ul>↵"
about_surf_lessons: "<ul>↵<li><strong>Surfen:</strong> je kunt kiezen uit de volgende surfpakketten:↵<ul>↵<li>Pakket S: 3 dagen surfles per week + gebruik surfmateriaal</li>↵<li>Pakket M: 5 dagen surfles per week + gebruik surfmateriaal</li>↵<li>Alleen gebruik surfmateriaal</li>↵<li>Er worden ook theorielessen gegeven</li>↵<li>Voor beginnende surfers raden wij Pakket L ten zeerste aan. Zeker in het begin is surfen een vrij lastig te leren sport, waarbij goede training vereist is</li>↵</ul>↵</li>↵<li><strong>Surfmateriaal:</strong> bij alle pakketten is het gebruik van het surfmateriaal (surfboard &amp; wetstuit) inbegrepen in de prijs van het verblijf. Het is echter wel zo dat de gasten die surflessen volgen, voorrang krijgen op het surfmateriaal. Meestal levert dit geen problemen op en zeker ook buiten de lessen om kan er gewoon gesurft worden.</li>↵</ul>↵<p>&nbsp;</p>↵"
about_transport: "<ul>↵<li><strong>Surfbus: </strong>de bussen naar Moliets vertrekken op vrijdagmiddag vanaf Amsterdam, Utrecht, Den Bosch, Breda, Antwerpen en Gent. De vertrektijd zal liggen tussen 13:00 en 18:30 uur. Op de zaterdag van jouw vertrek zal de bus aan het einde van de middag terugrijden richting België en Nederland, waar je dan zondagochtend aankomt. Rijdt vanaf 21 juni t/m 15 september 2019 (vertrek vrijdagmiddag, terugkomst zondagochtend).</li>↵<li><strong>Eigen vervoer:</strong> het is geen probleem om met de auto naar camping Moliets te komen. Er zijn mogelijkheden om gratis te parkeren.</li>↵</ul>↵"
accommodation: "Gedeelde en privé tenten"
accommodation_type: "Surfkamp"
activities_gallery: Array(3)
add_ons: Object
alert_checkbox: Array(1)
alert_text: "<p>Er zijn nog enkele plekken beschikbaar voor deze zomer, wacht niet met boeken!</p>↵"
arrival: "Aankomst en vertrek op zaterdag"
availability: "Raakt spoedig volgeboekt"
average_age: "18 - 25"
carousel: Array(3)
check-in-check-out: (...)
country: "Frankrijk"
covid: true

etc.etc.
```

Comment: Could you post the response data?

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I posted the response data in the post.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, if you're filtering posts, it must be done on the API side, so you get all the "France" posts, don't get unnecessary info, and don't waste memory.

If you can't filter it on API side (but why send URL parameters then) and getting all the posts, you can create a method like to use it to filter posts:

```
filterPostsByCountry: function() {
      return this.posts.filter(post => post.country === this.country);
}
```